# Number of consecutive TRUE's with shifts of 4 quarters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
Quarter      Tic  var
0            AAL  False
1            AAL  True
2            AAL  True
3            AAL  False
4            MSFT True
5            MSFT True
6            MSFT False
7            MSFT False
8            MSFT False
9            MSFT True
10           MSFT True
11           MSFT False
```

I want to count the number of consecutive quarters with a True value in the same quarter last year (so shifts of 4 periods) and with the same tic value and make this a new column. So, I want to do this for each unique value for tic. The required output is:

```
Quarter      tic  var    output
0            AAL  False  0
1            AAL  True   1
2            AAL  True   1
3            AAL  False  0
4            MSFT True   1
5            MSFT True   1
6            MSFT False  0
7            MSFT False  0
8            MSFT False  0
9            MSFT True   2
10           MSFT True   1
11           MSFT False  0
```

How should I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you please share with us the code you have so far, and explain where you are stuck?

Comment: Your output doesnt reveal what the pattern you are looking for.. do you mind put some light in here?

Comment: Ooh i gor what you want now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `groupby`:

```
quarters = np.arange(len(df))%4
blocks = (1-df['var'].astype(int)).groupby(quarters).cumsum()
df['output'] = df['var'].astype(int).groupby([blocks,quarters]).cumsum()
```

Out:

```
    Quarter    var  output
0         0  False       0
1         1   True       1
2         2   True       1
3         3  False       0
4         4   True       1
5         5   True       2
6         6  False       0
7         7  False       0
8         8  False       0
9         9   True       3
10       10   True       1
11       11  False       0
```

Comment: Is that grouping by indexes? Waht exaclty are you sending to the groupby function?

Comment: @adirabargil grouping by array of the same length. I'm passing `[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,...]` to the groupby, which indicates that I want to group the rows by steps of `4`.

Comment: @QuangHoang First of all thanks for helping. There are some minor differences between your output and the required output though. Quarter 6 for example should have output 0, but it gives 1

Comment: @t.pellegrom sorry, I missed the consecutive part. See updated answer.

Comment: @QuangHoang You are a lifesaver. This is allready really helpful! I expended my question slightly to include for different tic values (see updated question)